# Initializing slots based on other slot values in Common Lisp Object System class definitions

Tags: common-lisp, clos, slot

In my class definition, I want to initialize one slot based on the value of another slot.  Here is the sort of thing I would like to do:

```
(defclass my-class ()
  ((slot-1 :accessor my-class-slot-1 :initarg slot-1)
   (slot-2 :accessor my-class-slot-2 :initform (list slot-1))))
```

However this doesn't compile:

```
1 compiler notes:

Unknown location:
  warning: 
    This variable is undefined:
      SLOT-1

  warning: 
    undefined variable: SLOT-1
    ==>
      (CONS UC-2::SLOT-1 NIL)


Compilation failed.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `initialize-instance :after` documented [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_init_i.htm)

Comment: Is this or something equivalent possible using structs?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Doug Currie's answer expanded:

```
(defclass my-class ()
  ((slot-1 :accessor my-class-slot-1 :initarg :slot-1)
   (slot-2 :accessor my-class-slot-2)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after 
           ((c my-class) &rest args)
  (setf (my-class-slot-2 c) 
        (list (my-class-slot-1 c))))
```

Here's a call showing that it works:

```
> (my-class-slot-2 (make-instance 'my-class :slot-1 "Bob"))
("Bob")
```

See [this article](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/chap11-notes.html) for more details.

Comment: Zach Beane also gave this answer (or one almost like it) on comp.lang.lisp, but I didn't notice it before typing in my own code.  Thanks both Zach and Doug!

Answer (score 2):

```
(defparameter *self-ref* nil)


(defclass self-ref ()
  ()

  (:documentation "
Note that *SELF-REF* is not visible to code in :DEFAULT-INITARGS."))


(defmethod initialize-instance :around ((self-ref self-ref) &key)
  (let ((*self-ref* self-ref))
    (when (next-method-p)
      (call-next-method))))



(defclass my-class (self-ref)
  ((slot-1 :accessor slot-1-of :initarg :slot-1)
   (slot-2 :accessor slot-2-of
           :initform (slot-1-of *self-ref*))))




CL-USER> (let ((it (make-instance 'my-class :slot-1 42)))
           (values (slot-1-of it)
                   (slot-2-of it)))
42
42
CL-USER>
```