# Separating initialization arguments and class slots in Common Lisp Object System for making objects

Tags: oop, common-lisp, clos

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620249/initializing-slots-based-on-other-slot-values-in-common-lisp-object-system-class) asks about initializing slots from other slots. What I want to achieve instead is to take some arguments as input - perhaps but not necessarily to `make-instance` - and convert these arguments into the class slots for storage. In effect, I want to separate the implementation of the class from its (initialization) interface.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this?

The simplest way I can imagine is simply create a `(defun make-my-object ...)` as the interface. This may then call `make-instance` with appropriate arguments.

For example, imagine

```lisp
(defclass my-object () (slot-1 slot-2))
(defun make-my-object (arg-1 arg-2)
  (make-instance 'my-object 
                 :slot-1 (+ arg-1 arg-2) 
                 :slot-2 (- arg-1 arg-2)))
```

Other ways I can imagine include implementing an `initialize-instance :after` that takes `arg-1` and `arg-2` as keyword arguments and initializes `slot-1` and `slot-2` appropriately. However, since after methods are called in the least-specific-first-order, that means that superclass slots will be initialized before current-class slot. On the other hand, what looks more common is that one will take arguments for constructing current-class, and on the basis of these arguments, one will initialize the super-class slots.

The alternative is `initialize-instance :before` - or also `:around` - but if multiple classes in the hierarchy have such "interface-implementation" differences, I don't see this working, unless I can pass arguments to `call-next-method`.

Are there other ways?

EDIT: Thanks to @ignis volens for bringing to my notice that (one of) my main concern(s) is about superclass slots being initialized from subclass slots. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand your question.  The answer is almost certainly after methods on `initialize-instance` I think.  You say that this will cause slots defined in superclasses to be initialized first: yes, it will, and that almost certainly what you want to happen.  Slots defined in superclasses don't generally depend for their values on subclass slots (its always possible to think of exceptions to everything) and so initialising in least-specific first order is almost always what you want.

The two common ways of initializing slots that I use are either to simply declare what their initargs are in the definition:

```
(defclass minibeast ()
  ((legs :initform 'uncountable
         :initarg :legs
         :initarg :leg-count
         :accessor legs)
   (tentacles :initform 'many
              :initarg :tentacles
              :initarg :number-of-tentacles
              :accessor tentacles)))
```

And now `(make-instance 'minibeast :legs 87)` does what you expect.  And this works (because, obviously it has to if the two slots were defined in different classes):

```
(defclass awful-monster ()
  ((legs :initform 'uncountable
         :initarg :legs
         :initarg :leg-count
         :accessor legs)
   (appendages :initform 'many
               :initarg :legs
               :initarg :appendages)))
```

Now `(make-instance 'awful-monster :legs 93)` will result in an awful monster with 93 legs and 93 appendages.

However that method perhaps doesn't qualify as separating interface from implementation.  You may also want to perform some computation when initialising slots.  In both these cases after methods on `initialize-instance` are generally the right approach:

```
(defclass horrible-monster ()
  ((legs :initform 983
         :accessor legs)
   (eyes :initform 63
         :accessor eyes)
   (appendages
    :reader appendages)))
   
(defmethod initialize-instance :after
  ((m horrible-monster) &key eyes legs (stalky-eyes t))
  (with-slots ((e eyes) (l legs) appendages) m
    (when eyes (setf e eyes))
    (when legs (setf l legs))
    (setf appendages (if stalky-eyes (+ e l) l))))
```

And now horrible monsters will get the appropriate number of appendages (I am not sure why horrible monsters don't know whether their eyes are on stalks or not: perhaps they don't have mirrors).

There are any number of other combinations of course.  You might well not want to have user code call `make-instance` explicitly but wrap things up in some function:

```
(defun make-awful-thing (&rest args &key (sort-of-horrible-thing 'horrible-monster)
                               &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((the-remaining-args (copy-list args)))
    ;; No doubt alexandria or something has a way of doing this
    (remf the-remaining-args ':sort-of-horrible0thing)
    (apply #'make-instance sort-of-horrible-thing the-remaining-args)))
```

And now, of course you can have some bespoke initialzation protocol easily:

```
(defgeneric enliven-horrible-thing (horrible-thing &key)
  (:method :around ((horrible-thing t) &key)
   (call-next-method)
   t))

(defun make-awful-thing (&rest args &key (sort-of-horrible-thing 'horrible-monster)
                               &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((the-remaining-args (copy-list args)))
    ;; No doubt alexandria or something has a way of doing this
    (remf the-remaining-args ':sort-of-horrible0thing)
    (apply #'enliven-horrible-thing
           (apply #'make-instance sort-of-horrible-thing
                  the-remaining-args)
           the-remaining-args)))

(defmethod enliven-horrible-thing ((horrible-thing horrible-monster)
                                   &key (ichor t) (smell 'unspeakable))
  ...)
```

Comment: thinking about the Lisp alien logo right now

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! 
`Slots defined in superclasses don't generally depend for their values on subclass slots`
I think I should have stressed that this essentially forms my case. Continuing on the example, consider a complex-horrible-monster who can have different kinds of eyes and legs, with simple-horrible-monster being a subclass of it such that it has only a single kind of eye and leg; in this case, I'd want to initialize the superclass slots on the basis of the subclass slots. Or would there be another better way to think about this?

Comment: @digikar: What you're describing sounds like a design problem, but if you have two slots which can be independent in a superclass but should be the same in some subclass then either define, in the subclass, a common initarg for them, or initialise one from the other in an after method on `initialize-instance`.

Comment: @ignisvolens It's more of a list of different items in superclass vs list of same items in the subclass issue. But even then, I suppose redefining the superclass slots in the subclass, and doing the initialization in the initialize-instance method of the subclass makes me lose out on the validation code present in the initialize-instance method of the superclass. Would my best bet here be to separate out the validation code into a separate function? Or is there a CLOS-sy way to reuse the validation code without the separate function?

Comment: @digikar: you are not redefining the slots: you are extending their definitions.  All the `initialize-instance` methods in all the superclasses will do exactly what they already did: that's why they're after methods.  I suggest you actually try some examples (put calls to `print` or what have you to see what is happening) rather than simply guessing what might happen.

Comment: @ignisvolens Okay... Here's an attempt: https://pastebin.com/8p0EezHv
My problem would essentially be solved if the `horrible-monster` initialize-instance method is called *after* the `simple-horrible-monster` initialize-instance method, rather than *before*. Is there a way out? I suppose I can use `:before` methods to get the most-specific-first sequence, but would that be a "good" way to do such slot initialization and validation?

Comment: @digikar: As I said above, you have a design problem: CLOS is not going to fix that for you, and I'm not going to solve it for you.